# controlled range-slider component in react with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i am learning redux with react and trying to create an app where i have a range-slider, whose value dictates how many Box components will be rendered on the screen.

i am trying to make the range-slider a controlled component but can't make it change the store. i am getting no errors.

the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setBoxNumber } from '../actions/actions';

const Slider = ({ boxNumber, handleChange }) => {

    return(
        <div>
            <div>
                {boxNumber}
            </div>
            <div>
                <input 
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={boxNumber}
                    type="range" 
                    min="12" 
                    max="480" 
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { boxNumber: state.boxNumber }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    handleChange: (event) => dispatch(setBoxNumber(event.target.value))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Slider);
```

the reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

export const boxNumberReducer = (boxNumber = 40, action) => {
    switch(action.payload) {
        case 'SET_BOX_NUMBER':
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return boxNumber;
    }
}

export default combineReducers({
    boxNumber: boxNumberReducer
})
```

the action:

```
export const setBoxNumber = (number) => {
    return {
        type: 'SET_BOX_NUMBER',
        payload: number
    }
}
```

i also tried to call the handleChange method with an arrow function on change, like i would do with a controlled react component without redux, but it's making no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your reducer is configured incorrectly. You can pass all the initial states inside the variable `initialState` like this.

```
//reducer.js
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

const initialState = {
  boxNumber: 40,
};

const boxReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_BOX_NUMBER":
      return {
        ...state,
        boxNumber: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default combineReducers({
  boxReducer,
});
```

This is how your index.js file should look like:

```
//index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Slider from "./Slider.js";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducer from "./redux/reducer";

const store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Slider />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

You need to update your `mapStateToProps` in `Slider.js` to access the states in your reducer.

```
//Slider.js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { boxNumber: state.boxReducer.boxNumber };
};
```

This is a simple fix. As your app gets bigger, you'll need more reducers and thus it's better to keep a separate file for that.

Comment: when trying this i get the error:
```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {boxNumber}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```
nothing i found online relates to my case as i understand, any ideas?

Comment: Yes. I figured your store is also not configured correctly. So I have updated the code.

Comment: thank you so much! that did the trick. so if i get it correctly, the value is basically kept in the reducer object inside the state object? so of every different state i want to grab i need to "reach" into the seperate reducer inside state?